# Tensorflow semantic segmentation gives zero loss

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I am training a model for segmenting machine printed text from the images. The images might contain barcodes and handwritten text also. Ground truths images are processed so that 0 represents machine print and 1 represents the remaining. And I am using 5 layer CNN with dilation which outputs 2 maps in the end.

And my loss is calculated as follows:

```
def loss(logits, labels):

    logits = tf.reshape(logits, [-1, 2])
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])

    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels)
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
```

And I have some images which contain only handwritten text and their corresponding ground truths are blank pages which are represented by 1s.

When I train the model, for these images I am getting a loss of 0 and training accuracy of 100%. Is this correct? How can this loss be zero?
For other images which contain barcodes or machine print, am getting some loss and they are converging properly.

And when I test this model, barcodes are correctly ignored. But it outputs both machine print and handwritten text where I need only machine print.

Can someone guide me on where I am going wrong, please!

UPDATE 1:

I was using a learning rate of 0.01 before and changing it to 0.0001 gave me some loss and it seems to converge but not very well.
But, then how a high learning rate will give a loss of 0?

When I use the same model in Caffe with learning rate of 0.01 it gave some loss and it converges well compared to in Tensorflow.

Comment: Are your logits and labels one-hot-encoded?

Comment: @marcopah  Yes. I think I am doing that in the first 2 lines of loss function described in the question. My logits are of shape [batch_size, num_classes] and labels are of shape [batch_size] as recommended in tensorflow docs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your loss calculation looks fine but a loss of zero is weird in your case. Have you tried playing with the learning rate? Maybe decrease it. I have encountered weird loss values and decreasing the learning rate helped me.

Comment: While this is probably helpful feedback, I think it would make more sense as a comment rather than an answer.